# What does one call an individual receiving a subsidy?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

If a subsidiary is a company; what does one call an *individual* receiving a subsidy?
*'Recipient'* would be an obvious choice—I was wondering if there is a more specific word?

Comment: From OED - **subsidiary** (adj. and noun) 3b: *maintained or retained by subsidies.*

Comment: "Subsidiary" as company has nothing to do with your question.  A subsidiary company is one that is completely owned/controlled by another company.  Subsidy as in *grant* is not part of the definition, in that case.  So it's just irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks itsbruce, you're on the money there (so to speak), so what would I call one who receives a subsidy, then? Is there even a word for this?

Comment: Oops, didn't see your comment, @FumbleFingers. It's quite annoying when a specific, popular nuance of a word renders all other definitions obsolete. I suppose I should keep with "Recipient of such-and-such subsidy", then...

Comment: Are you looking for a word which unambiguously labels somebody as "recipient of subsidy", so that you don't need to say "of subsidy"?  Sadly, I suspect you are out of luck, if so.  Otherwise, "beneficiary" is as close as I can think of.

Comment: Aye, that's what I was afraid of, @itsbruce . When it comes to government subsidies, one is never labeled "beneficiary" even nearly quite as often as one is labeled "burden", I'm afraid. Perhaps "Subsidiasee", or "subsidiaree" could be coined?
In any case, thanks muchly for your help!

Comment: @neologimancer: It all depends on your exact context. I suspect the governing bodies of many UK agencies distributing "subsidies" (whether financed by government or other funds) would encourage the staff to refer to recipients as ***clients***.

Answer (score 0):

An individual receiving a subsidy: **Beneficiary**.

Comment: Please do not quote (even/especially as images) from works without citing them. That is considered plagiarism on Stack Exchange sites, and moderators are instructed to delete questions and answers that contain unattributed citations on sight.